# Webpack stopped transpiling React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've been using WebPack v2.6.1 to transpile and bundle my react `jsx` code. I did not change anything. All of a sudden, WebPack stopped transpiling and bundling my React code for production.

Below is a part of the error messages I'm getting:
[image]

When I use webpack dev server, everything works perfectly fine. This is happening when I try to go to production. WebPack seems to be producing the bundled output files but when I try to pull up the page, they don't come up. I'm issuing the same `webpack --env.process` command I've always used. In the browser, this is the error I'm getting which is preventing my React component from displaying.

[image]

My `webpack.config.js` file is below. Any idea what's happening here?

```
var IS_DEV = false; // change to false if building production files

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require("path");

// Define plugins needed for production and dev cases
var _pluginsDev = [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'fetch': 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
        moment: 'moment',
        ps: 'perfect-scrollbar'
    }),

];
var _pluginsProd = [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'fetch': 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
        moment: 'moment',
        ps: 'perfect-scrollbar'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // Minimizer, removing multiple occurances of imports et.c
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        compress: true,
        output: { comments: false }
    })
];

var _devtool = IS_DEV ? 'eval' : 'cheap-module-source-map';
var _plugins = IS_DEV ? _pluginsDev : _pluginsProd;
var _fileName = IS_DEV ? "./build/[name]-bundle.js" : "./dist/[name]-bundle.js";

var _bundles = {
    home: './UI/components/home/home.jsx',
    accounts: './UI/components/accounts/accounts.jsx',
    contacts: './UI/components/contacts/contacts.jsx',
    projectsList: './UI/components/projects/projects_list/projectsList.jsx'
};

module.exports = {
    entry: _bundles,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot"),
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: _fileName
    },
    devtool: _devtool,
    plugins: _plugins,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'stage-0', 'react']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't change ANYTHING?? If you rollback to a previous version of your codebase does it still not work?

Comment: Nothing at all in front-end code.

Comment: Not sure what to go back to but I guess I can go back to something that I checked into the repo last month to see if that will do anything. Do these errors mean anything?

Comment: You could try `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.

Comment: @ThomasDevries I'll give it a try and post back. Thanks.